How can optimize my cost on firebase/google cloud?
I have a game that people upload their levels and play.
As you can see in the chart, my daily cost increases drastically. And most of the cost comes from "Bandwidth". With this increase, I believe my cost would be over $100 at the end of the month and would reach $200 in the next month.

Would it be cheaper if I used google cloud directly instead of firebase?
Is S3 a better option for me?
Do you think Cloud CDN or Media CDN would fit in my case?



The answer to a cost optimization question might be more a business decision rather than (solely) a technical one. When your earnings increase at the same rate or more than your operating costs and your app is turning a profit: then refactoring your application design might be more expensive and not required in the short time IMHO.  But if the bulk of your data traffic is content that can be hosted elsewhere or downloads can be shifted to a CDN solution leveraging such technologies is indeed an option. But try one of the cost calculators to see what will happen before you make such a change.

if you want a good deal stay away from the big providers and go with one of the scrappy competitors. also ask you devs to find a more compact representation of the data. for a CDN cloudflare is a deal until they decide they want all your money,
